# Пытаюсь засунуть в переменную guild мой сервер но ничего не выходит. Как исправить?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Мой код:

```
import config
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

bot = Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
guild = bot.get_guild(720618721244348428)
print(guild)
```

в переменной `guild` записалось значение `None` как эту ошибку исправить?

Comment: Потому что у вас даже бот не запущен, чтобы запросы отправлять. Создайте хотя бы обработчик события `on_ready()`, и уже в нем получайте сервер. И БОТА ЗАПУСТИТЕ

Comment: Спасибо огромное!